# Can you say a system is a "productive system" to mean the same as a "production system" (as opposed to a test deployment of said system)?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-difference

I see a lot of people around me use this phrase, but it sounds wrong to me: "The security test will be performed on the productive system" rather than "... on the production system". The context is a system (such as a server) that is used by real users, i.e. for production work, rather than solely for development or testing purposes.

Searching online, it seems to be incorrect to substitute the word, but I can't find anything that answers the question directly. The main pointer is simply the number of times one phrase ("productive system" vs "production system") is used in the context that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In software development, it is quite common to describe a *live* system as the *production environment*. This is because the system is not for testing, but for production and is pointing at a live database. This is common IT terminology.

I have not heard a live system or environment called "a *productive* system" and don't believe this is common terminology.

From a linguistic point of view, something that is "productive" is producing results, or capable of producing results, and so it might seem reasonable to *describe* a working system as "productive"; however if your intention is to label it as such then I think you should stick to accepted terminology.